# Retrieve columns data for each line csv

Tags: php, file, csv

I want to retrieve for each line all data for a specific column of a csv file.

File structure

```
Swimlane,Column,ID,Title
```

For example retrieve all data for the column "Title".

Code:

```
    $row = 1;
    if (($handle = fopen("Business Backlog API Publication.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            // Column title            
            $num = $data[4];
            echo "<p> $num : $row: <br /></p>\n";
            $row++;
            for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If file is not huge, you can use file() function:

```
$lines = file("Business Backlog API Publication.csv");

$row = 0;

foreach($lines as $line)
{
    $line = explode(",", $line);
    $title = $line[3];

    echo "<p> $row : $title: <br /></p>\n";

    $row++;
}
```

Note that title is at index 3, not 4

Comment: Thank you. But I want to adapt it with a system research. For example I indicate in form in a field "Title" or "ID" and the result is for each line all data for the specified column

Comment: So, is the problem to have a form in which you can select the field and send it to the search alghoritm?

Comment: The problem is the search algorithm

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think I didn't undersand the question. Can you please smiplify the explanation with an example?